# How to visualize an array which represents a warehouse?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-visualization

For my current project I'm trying to visualize the traffic in a warehouse, so I'm interested in finding how often each shelf gets picked. I now have the a 2D array with objects, where an object can either be a path inbetween shelves, a wall or a shelf. Each shelf has it's own number which indicates it's location. Now I have a dictionary with keys the number which indicates the location, and as value the amount of times it has been picked. Code is really long so I'll put it at the bottom, but it's mostly array initializing. It gives the following output:

```
-1  0   0   11  54  54  0   0   0   0   43  43  0   0   75  75  89  89  63  63  48  48  26  283
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   175 175 360 360 49  49  48  48  47  47  8   8   121 121 20  20  15  15  67  0
0   0   0   0   37  37  16  16  20  20  15  15  37  37  70  70  110 110 47  47  17  17  54  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   315 315 17  17  27  27  29  29  30  30  51  51  18  18  42  42  10  10  63  0
0   0   0   0   57  57  42  42  21  21  8   8   21  21  4   4   6   6   55  55  20  20  37  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   152 152 7   7   59  59  140 140 48  48  64  64  27  27  14  14  12  12  46  0
0   0   0   0   66  66  73  73  119 119 5   5   34  34  119 119 88  88  69  69  21  21  142 0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   5   31  31  49  49  70  70  23  23  10  10  50  50  166 166 68  68  602 602 185 0
0   0   0   0   24  24  54  54  33  33  17  17  75  75  54  54  63  63  75  75  66  66  81  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   108 108 116 116 131 131 79  79  239 239 331 331 147 147 121 121 113 113 150 0
0   0   0   0   169 169 111 111 145 145 77  77  42  42  17  17  44  44  66  66  113 0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   95  0   138 109 0   95  7   0   18  0   0   0   0   0   16  8   0   0   0   0   42
0   0   0   95  0   138 109 0   95  7   0   18  0   0   0   0   0   16  8   0   0   0   0   42
0   0   2   292 0   163 67  0   180 40  0   52  5   0   69  81  0   41  88  0   56  38  0   58
0   0   2   292 0   163 67  0   180 40  0   52  5   0   69  81  0   41  88  0   56  38  0   58
0   0   0   103 0   95  113 0   145 44  0   62  49  0   65  68  0   50  78  0   72  55  0   40
0   0   0   103 0   95  113 0   145 44  0   62  49  0   65  68  0   50  78  0   72  55  0   40
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   72  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   88
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   72  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   88
85  0   245 34  0   192 70  0   20  52  0   77  44  0   44  50  0   112 133 0   117 68  0   153
85  0   245 34  0   192 70  0   20  52  0   77  44  0   44  50  0   112 133 0   117 68  0   153
113 0   300 23  0   114 58  0   162 47  0   36  48  0   316 28  0   179 178 0   139 136 0   74
113 0   300 23  0   114 58  0   162 47  0   36  48  0   316 28  0   179 178 0   139 136 0   74
65  0   68  42  0   150 53  0   198 119 0   25  72  0   44  62  0   92  112 0   161 66  0   193
65  0   68  42  0   150 53  0   198 119 0   25  72  0   44  62  0   92  112 0   161 66  0   193
242 0   196 77  0   442 119 0   142 188 0   24  44  0   94  79  0   51  116 0   124 53  0   163
242 0   196 77  0   442 119 0   142 188 0   24  44  0   94  79  0   51  116 0   124 53  0   163
182 0   157 85  0   145 165 0   39  473 0   33  72  0   141 115 0   113 130 0   127 68  0   81
182 0   157 85  0   145 165 0   39  473 0   33  72  0   141 115 0   113 130 0   127 68  0   81
93  0   181 147 0   220 47  0   190 0   0   343 38  0   377 54  0   120 100 0   113 87  0   105
93  0   181 147 0   220 47  0   190 0   0   343 38  0   377 54  0   120 100 0   113 87  0   105
190 0   105 291 0   329 552 0   42  0   0   347 628 0   26  76  0   145 340 0   209 197 0   133
190 0   105 291 0   329 552 0   42  0   0   347 628 0   26  76  0   145 340 0   209 197 0   133
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
326 0   261 99  0   163 140 0   161 113 0   44  75  0   154 100 0   315 90  0   257 93  0   0
326 0   261 99  0   163 140 0   161 113 0   44  75  0   154 100 0   315 90  0   257 93  0   0
102 0   164 147 0   151 164 0   117 87  0   89  53  0   227 266 0   136 82  0   1046    128 0   69
102 0   164 147 0   151 164 0   117 87  0   89  53  0   227 266 0   136 82  0   1046    128 0   69
32  0   100 210 0   85  39  0   34  84  0   21  129 0   309 123 0   53  145 0   351 34  0   43
32  0   100 210 0   85  39  0   34  84  0   21  129 0   309 123 0   53  145 0   351 34  0   43
36  0   141 132 0   267 68  0   90  74  0   38  60  0   127 186 0   176 239 0   53  191 0   100
36  0   141 132 0   267 68  0   90  74  0   38  60  0   127 186 0   176 239 0   53  191 0   100
358 0   531 468 0   246 35  0   99  150 0   83  76  0   56  181 0   57  111 0   142 190 0   178
358 0   531 468 0   246 35  0   99  150 0   83  76  0   56  181 0   57  111 0   142 190 0   178
107 0   128 221 0   198 85  0   88  114 0   99  78  0   146 163 0   193 91  0   84  87  0   84
107 0   128 221 0   198 85  0   88  114 0   99  78  0   146 163 0   193 91  0   84  87  0   84
268 0   105 130 0   126 32  0   100 207 0   50  455 0   32  60  0   713 72  0   68  72  0   201
268 0   105 130 0   126 32  0   100 207 0   50  455 0   32  60  0   713 72  0   68  72  0   201
491 0   21  155 0   27  0   0   90  0   0   9   107 0   611 143 0   36  47  0   26  85  0   81
491 0   21  155 0   27  0   0   90  0   0   9   107 0   611 143 0   36  47  0   26  85  0   81
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   227 205 0   122 130 0   102 25  0   0   0   0   0   30  0   14  46  0   153 298 0   32
370 0   227 205 0   122 130 0   102 25  0   0   0   0   0   30  0   14  46  0   153 298 0   32
0   0   555 78  0   187 102 0   127 0   0   0   0   0   0   43  0   41  308 0   135 0   0   0
1026    0   555 78  0   18  7 102   0   127 0   0   0   0   0   0   43  0   41  308 0   135 0   0   0
0   0   287 45  0   46  137 0   114 2   0   0   0   0   0   42  0   130 46  0   459 92  0   0
572 0   287 45  0   46  137 0   114 2   0   0   0   0   0   42  0   130 46  0   459 92  0   0
0   0   564 81  0   21  91  0   62  6   0   0   0   0   0   25  0   124 78  0   73  0   0   0
0   0   564 81  0   21  91  0   62  6   0   0   0   0   0   25  0   124 78  0   73  0   0   0
0   0   746 107 0   35  159 0   67  9   0   0   0   0   0   55  0   147 52  0   0   0   0   0
```

Which corresponds to the following layout: [image: layout]
How would be the best way to visualize this using windows Forms?

Comment: Do you need the cells to be editable, or this is just a visualization? Is data entry going to be happening on this application?

Comment: Also, what is the significance of values outside of the boundaries, and the values inside the boundaries? The most straightforward way for me would be to take a floor plan vector graphic and overlay the numbers where they need to be. You need to code a mini CAD system to display graphical objects using `Graphics.DrawLine()` etc, or maybe there is a library out there to do this.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou for now it's only visualization, I'm currently using textboxes and arranged them in such a way that they represent the map but I'm not getting much further..

Comment: There is a `TableLayoutPanel` for the grid layout, and possibly `TextBoxArray` from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatiblity`.

Comment: Or you can try a `DataGridView` as a 70×24 table